# Add a "Contact us" form on each product

Tags: forms, contact-us, contact-form

I would like to add a "Contact us" form on each product; I've copied the contact form and added to the cms static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" form_action="/contacts/index/post/" template="catalog/product/view/form-personalizzazione.phtml"}}
```

The problem is, how can we change it so it doesn't redirect on contact page but it remains inside the product instead?

Inside phtml it starts with

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to either **rewrite** the Contact controller located at `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`

or alternatively create your own module and controller action, and use that as the form action.

So for example, change the form action to be something like:

```
{{block type="core/template" form_action="/modulename/index/post/" template="catalog/product/view/form-personalizzazione.phtml"}}
```

Within your Module controller `postAction()` method you could then either redirect ***back*** to the previous page or get the product from the ***registry*** and use it's `Mage::registry('current_product')->getUrl()` method data.

Comment: where exactly do I have to change/add Mage::registry('current_product')->getUrl() ? thanks

Comment: You can return a redirect to the product URL within the postAction() method. Essentially change where the returned redirects are in the normal post action

Comment: meaning from   $this->_redirect('*/*/');     to    Mage::registry('current_product')->getUrl();  ?

Comment: You should be able to do something like $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')->getUrl());

Comment: ok I've edited that, now I've added this block <block  type="core/template" name="ProdottiController" form_action="catalog/product/view/form-personalizzazione.phtml" ></block> to catalog.xml  and this {{block type="core/template" form_action="/ProdottiController/index/post/"  template="catalog/product/view/form-personalizzazione.phtml"}} inside the custom tab but i get a 404 error, I think I made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: The form action should all be in lowercase. That first section should be the frontname that you have defined in the config.xml file of the module, the second part is the file name and the third is the action. So essentially it does [frontname]/[controller]/[action]

Comment: Is there maybe a more detailed guide for this?

Comment: It might be worth looking at alternative questions on stack exchange that helps with the creation of a module /w a controller. If you find that this answer is correct for your question, please do accept it as correct!